# What are the benefits of normality assumption for AR(I)MA models?

Tags: time-series, arima, data-transformation, normality-assumption

I know normality assumption is not necessary for all of the ARIMA models. My question is that if we have a non-normal time series, is it better to transform it to normal state by transformations like Box-Cox and then use it in the model? what are the pros and cons of these transformation in ARIMA models?

Comment: How do you know that *normality assumption is not necessary for all of the ARIMA models*? Could you give a reference?